# Run code after fixtures loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, minitest, searchkick

I'm using Rails 5.1 with Minitest and Searchkick gem and in my system tests I need to have the data indexed in ElasticSearch to make sure the tests pass.

If I add a breakpoint and inspect

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  require 'pry'; binding.pry

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

all my models have zero records, assuming I've recreated the database with:
`rails db:drop db:create db:migrate`

So how can I have the code `Model.reindex` running after the loading of fixtures?

Note: I could use the `setup` but that way I will do a reindex in all needed models before each test, increasing the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a class variable in your setup method like this:

```
class SomeTest
  setup do
    @@once ||= Model.reindex
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on the CI server. I fixed it by preloading the test database before running the tests.

```sh
bin/rails db:fixtures:load
```

(Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html)